# How to store data from firestore locally on mobile?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app we have messaging facility which allows user to have conversation with admin. But whenever user get onto the message screen all the message documents get's loaded.
Right now I am requesting all the message documents from firestore as a stream in a streambuilder which eventually make changes whenever new message arrives.

My question is - how can I store the messages as a list in the mobile so that I will only request message documents after the last loaded message on mobile and I won't request all the message documents every time. I think this will exponentially reduce the document reads from the billing.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#configure-offline-persistence?

Comment: I have seen this but this doesn't satisfy my requirements

Comment: "doesn't satisfy my requirements" It would help if you say why not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

--- But either way, if the built-in persistence doesn't work, you'll have to build your own persistence layer. If you want to request only modified documents, you'll need to store a `lastModified` timestamp in each document and a `lastCheckedForModifiedDocuments` timestamp in the local storage of each client. With those two pieces of information you can then build the query that is needed to updated you custom persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create  observable list of your message model and add every message your user send to admin then store it on the shared preferences and you  can determine time for clearing database not to have all your message has added , if you wanna to have some special messages in databse and still after that delay be there you can implement sth like whatsapp and star your messages and not to delete them by filer or another. that was scenario witch came in my mind after reading your question and hope to help you I will leave some links down below about shared preference package and one video to learn how to use as you use case
sorry it was to long but I had explained what I can implement
links:
[shared_preferences: ^2.0.13](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyz0HrGUamc)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).